Photodiode reverse light current question
I am looking at a photodiode BPV10NF and it says the typical reverse light current is 55 μA.
In the lab, I have found that the light current keeps increasing with light intensity well past 300 μA when I put an IR LED closer and closer.
What are the consequences of operating photodiodes at higher light currents, say at 100 μA continuously? Is power dissipation the limiting factor?
I am struggling to understand what the light current ratings on PIN photodiodes are used for and what defines the maximum if I can drive them all much higher with higher light intensity.  I have looked at many different manufacturers datasheets and they don't give a clear explanation.


I am looking at a photodiode BPV10NF and it says the typical reverse light current is 55uA.


If you look more closely, what it is saying is that if you put in 1 mW/cm2 of light at 870 nm, then your expected photocurrent is typically 55 uA and no less than 30 uA.  If you use a different amount of light or a different wavelength, then you should not expect those values.

What are the consequences of operating photodiodes at higher light currents, say at 100uA continuously? Is power dissipation the limiting factor?

There is a spec for power dissipation:

So you do need to keep the power dissipated well under that limit to avoid damage.  Beyond that I would expect that the device performs normally, although possibly the response becomes less linear at high intensity.

I am struggling to understand what the light current ratings on PIN photodiodes are used for and what defines the maximum if I can drive them all much higher with higher light intensity.

The current per power rating is essentially how sensitive the device is (combination of responsivity and lens size).  You would use it to determine if the device is sensitive enough for your application.  The maximum is whatever the limits in the absolute maximum say.

So you're saying if the absolute maximum limits for the reverse light current are missing, then I can defer to the power rating? In this specific case 215mW / 50V = 4300uA. Does this mean I can comfortably put 1000uA through it with no damage?

On a related note, would you be kind enough to explain the "short circuit current". I see that it is also 50uA which is confusing. Is it the current at which the junction has no resistance?

@MacDaraCurran 1 mA is a reasonable amount of current for a photodiode and I don't see anything in the datasheet suggesting that would be a problem, so I think so.  Open circuit voltage and short circuit current refer to the max voltage/current the device will generate when run in photovoltaic mode (no reverse voltage) at the specified illumination.  If you're running in photoconductive mode they're not important.

RE "The current per power rating is essentially the sensitivity of the device.", This is the responsivity of the device. The sensitivity is the lowest optical power level that can be distinguished from noise and is given in the datasheet with the name "noise equivalent power". (Admittedly the Vishay datasheet also seems to misuse the term sensitivity)

How would you factor optical power vs electrical power. e.g. an optical laser at a distance say PD @ 0V yields 100 mA  what power is it?

The power dissipation is probably the limiting factor.
Note that the datasheet gives the 215mW limit at T<25'C, so you must derate the maximum power dissipation for ambient temperature. 215mW represents the maximum 75'C of self-heating from 25'C to the maximum junction temperature of 100'C at the datasheet thermal resistance of 350K/W.
For example, if your maximum ambient temperature is to be 70'C you'd limit it 99mW. At 50V Vr that's ~2mA, so 1mA would appear to be safe, but you'd have to consider the heating from your light source and other sources as well in picking that maximum Ta.

How would you factor optical power vs electrical power. e.g. an optical laser at a distance say a PD @ 0V yields 100 mA  what power is it?  55m ?

@D.A.S. Not sure I understand the question. If the PD is in photoconductive mode and producing no output power (0V) then whatever gets absorbed is lost as heat, whatever the PD current might be.

The question is clear. Optical power is absorbed. But the internal loss is not since there is a current sink with ESR shunted externally. So internal voltage and ESR are unknowns. Yet we know the spec is 0.55mA/mW with 0V
